# SVG is displayed with wrong colors

Tags: reactjs, image, web, svg, gatsby

I have an [SVG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMzDO.jpg) that I import in my React web page. The problem is the [SVG displayed has some of its colors wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Fsf.jpg).

As you can see on the web page, there are 3 SVG. 2 of them are displayed with wrong colors. But the first one has original colors. Although the 3 SVG are **imported and used exactly the same way.**

In MyPage.jsx, I import them

```
import Hanshake from '../images/handshake.svg';
import Logistics from '../images/logistics.svg';
import Designer from '../images/designer.svg';
```

Then simply use it like this:

```
    <Col xs={24} md={8} className='about_illustration_text'>
      <Hanshake />
      Some text
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} md={8} className='about_illustration_text'>
      <Logistics />
      Some text
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} md={8} className='about_illustration_text'>
      <Designer />
      Some text
    </Col>
```

I didn't find any CSS conflicting.

What's wrong with those SVG ?

- [First SVG codepen](https://codepen.io/fekiv70977/pen/JjGwNJp)
- [2nd SVG codepen](https://codepen.io/fekiv70977/pen/LYGMyLm)
- [3rd SVG codepen](https://codepen.io/fekiv70977/pen/dyGwWRj)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There *are* conflicting CSS rules. Each SVG uses `<linearGradient>` definitions (look inside the `<defs>` sections), and they use the same Ids.

These Gradients get referenced by style attributes like this:

```
style="fill:url(#_Linear11);"
```

After inserting all SVG content into one page, there are multiple `<linearGradient>` elements with the same id as part of the same DOM. Ids must be unique throughout a page, or references will overwrite each other.

Comment: Thanks @ccprog and Ferran Buireu for your answers, it now works !

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting your `fill` styles with the `fill:url(#_Linear1)` rule (the `#_Linear1` part). If you put 2 of that SVG in the same CodePen, you will see how they change its `fill` since they are conflicting. Things gets odd with 3 in the same file.

Change your `url(#_Linear1)` to a `rgb` plain color/background or use a unique identifier for each background element.

Comment: Just to clarify, that is why they look good when they are on separate pages hence the codepens you shared, but not when they are all on the same page.